# how to get some key and value from json using jq

Tags: json, key, jq

Here is my test.json file

```
{
  "top": "0",
  "sub": {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3"
  }
}
```

I can use jq like this: cat test.json | jq '.top, .sub.two'

It returns:

```
"0"
"2"
```

Is it possible to return the key as well? So like below:

```
"top": "0"
"two": "2"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a valid JSON output:

```
{top} + (.sub | {two})
```